# Rails, Paperclip, DelayedJob and cleaning temporary files

Tags: ruby, paperclip, delayed-job

In a Ruby on Rails application, I'm using Paperclip to handle attached files. The download (from a URL) and attachment is done in a background job (with DelayedJob).

Each job might deal with many files to download, and it results to a dozens of temporary files left in the /tmp directory.

Sometimes, some temp files are left in the filesystem until the DelayedJob worker is restarted.

I wonder if there is a way to manually clean the temp files.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could do this automatically with a regularly scheduled job, schedules with regular cron, or with something like the Clockwork gem or resque-scheduler if you want to avoid cron's syntax. Have it look for temp files in the given directory; it's easiest if it's a specific subdirectory under /tmp, and delete all files that are more than 10 minutes old, or whatever age makes sense for your application. Run that job once a day, or several times a day, and you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tempfile`.

> A utility class for managing temporary files.

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo')
begin
    # process here
ensure
    file.close
    file.unlink    # deletes the temp file
end
```